# Javascript - Need a regex to match US Schedule B (HTS) numbers. "0000.00.0000"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I can't seem to get this right. 
I need a regex to only allow numbers and decimals (0-9), and be in these formats:

```
 1234.56.7890
```

or

```
 1234567890
```

It can start with a 0, but must be 10 digits (if no decimals), or 12 digits with decimals in correct location (xxxx.xx.xxxx).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: So can the number actually be 10 digits without decimals? Or is that just something you are mentioning that's irrelevant to the actual value. Doing a quick google shows me a list of codes that all follow the format of `[4].[2].[4]` with some group headers matching `[2 or 4].[2]`. This matters because everyone is going to give an answer that matches both options, when one might not be actually valid.

Comment: Yes, it can be 10 digits without decimals or 12 with decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `^\d{4}(\.?)\d{2}\1\d{4}$` here. The `^` and `$` anchors are used to force the complete string to match. `(\.?)` matches the dot if present, the `\1` forces a dot again, if the first is matched or no dot if it is not.

You can find some matching and non matching examples [here](https://regex101.com/r/JQ8PDN/1).

Comment: This looks to be perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This one should work: `/^(\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})|(\d{10})$/`.

It will match every string with the pattern:
`xxxx.xx.xxxx` and `xxxxxxxxxx` (x being a number).

Comment: You should escape your `.`'s or else it means one of any character and not a literal `.`.

Answer (score 1):

`^((\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})|(\d{10}))$`

Notice that the point symbol should be escaped.

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
1st Capturing Group ((\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})|(\d{10}))
1st Alternative (\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})
2nd Capturing Group (\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})
\d{4} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
{4} Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
\d{2} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
{2} Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
\d{4} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
2nd Alternative (\d{10})
3rd Capturing Group (\d{10})
\d{10} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
{10} Quantifier — Matches exactly 10 times
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```

You can find the explanation of any regex and test it using sites https://regex101.com/ or http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this regex `([0-9]{10})|([0-9]{4}(.)[0-9]{2}(.)[0-9]{4})` and it seems to respond to your question.

Tested on [this link](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score -2):

```
/\d\{4}\.\{0,1}\d\{2}\.\{0,1}\d\{4}
```

is a slight improvement on nicovank's answer, since .{0,1} matches only one or zero dots while naked '.' will match a single instance of any character

Comment: This allows for there to be only one `.` though. Also, you have extra escape characters in front of your quantifier groups. Also, `{0,1}` is the same thing as `?`, both mean 0 or 1 of the previous character.

Comment: This regex is not the same as nicovank's. This matches `000000.0000` which his does not.